# Join with resulted table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
p.slugUrl AS resultslug, p.id, m.slugUrl, m.categoryParent, pa.pageId, pa.categoryId from tcs_pagecontents as p,tcs_pageassociation as pa, tcs_menucategory_site as m where p.id=pa.pageId and pa.categoryId=m.id ;
```

This is returning a table with following structure( lets say this table as P)

```
resultslug
id
slugUrl
categoryParent
pageId
categoryId
```

Further I wanted to make a join with this resulted table to another table where P.categoryParent = T.id, here T is another table I wanted to fetch the following coloumn name

```
    P.resultslug
    P.id
    P.slugUrl
    P.categoryParent
    P.pageId
    P.categoryId
    T.slugUrl
where  P.categoryParent = T.id;
```

I am getting blank here. Any Idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you look at SQL joins? It will help you join multiple tables based on criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Just join that table like the other ones.

```
select p.slugUrl AS resultslug, p.id, m.slugUrl, m.categoryParent, pa.pageId, pa.categoryId, T.slugURL 
from tcs_pagecontents as p
join tcs_pageassociation as pa on p.id=pa.pageId 
join tcs_menucategory_site as m on pa.categoryId=m.id
join another_table T on m.categoryParent = T.id;
```

Comment: Not Working getting following error:-
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join tcs_pageassociation as pa on p.id=pa.pageId 
join tcs_menucategory_site as ' at line 3

Comment: awh that was my stupid mistake. Its running now. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @NituDhaka, sorry there was a typo, removed the `,` after `as p`